# Trying to email links to php that display pdfs in Firefox - Mac

Tags: php, macos, email, firefox, pdf

I'm sending links to php pages that then generate and/or display a pdf file. The link appears to function correctly (navigating to the php page from the user's email client and displaying the pdf in the browser) on all browsers except for Firefox on the Mac. Instead, it prompts the user to download the php file.

Does anyone else have experience with this? Is there any way around it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I always thought that was a function of Firefox itself, no? http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/view-pdf-files-firefox-without-downloading-them?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Opening+PDF+files+within+Firefox